# Is it possible to download electronically signed document with a signature on it?

Tags: pdf, digital-signature

I am sorry if this is a wrong place to ask this. If it is, redirect me to the right site.

A document is electronically signed and sent me in `.asice` file. I managed to open the document via my countries e-signature website, but when I tried to download it, the downloaded version didn't have a signature on it (it was a pdf file).

I am aware of an option of electronically signing a pdf or word file, but this time, I am not the one who signs the document, I just need the other persons signature. And now I don't know how do I get this `.asice` file with a signature, which I can download. Can anyone has any experience with this?

Comment: This is a problem of the website. You cannot get a signature, only a signed document.

Comment: @harrymc Ok, so you mean that there is no possibility to print this signed document, so that the signature would be visible?

Comment: You might be able to work with the file using the right tool. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The
[ASiC Extended (ASiC-E)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Signature_Containers#ASiC_Extended_%28ASiC-E%29)
is a container that can hold one or more files, signatures and
time assertion files.
The files in the container can themselves be signed or not, depending
on the person that created the container.

You can on Windows install the
[DigiDoc4 Client](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/digidoc4-client/9pfpfk4dj1s6#activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
from the Microsoft Store, described as:

> DigiDoc4 Client is a part of Estonian national ID-card software developed by Aktors on behalf of governmental institution - Estonian Information System’s Authority.
>
> DigiDoc4 Client is a program that can be used to sign digitally with ID-card and Mobile-ID, check the validity of digital signatures, open and save documents inside the signature container, encrypt and decrypt files and review personal information stored on the ID-card.

I would suggest installing DigiDoc4 Client and using it to extract the file.
It may also give you some information about the signature.
I don't know enough about this tool to know if it can also use the signature
to extract the contained files as signed, if they were not already signed
when put into the container.